# how to add days to date(set in jlabel)

Tags: java, swing

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
Date date3=null;
try {
date3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").parse(jLabel1.getText());
System.out.println(date3);       
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");             
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date3);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
String expDateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
jLabel2.setText(expDateString);                   
} 
catch (ParseException ex)
{
Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

jlabel1 input value is :29-09-2014.>
 Add 1 day.expected output is:30-09-2014.(jlabel2)
 But  No error occured,output displayed:30-12-2014.(meaningless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
dd-MM-YYYY
```

to

```
dd-MM-yyyy
```

Because your format `String` is incorrect, per the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Javadoc,

> ```
> Letter    Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
> G         Era designator          Text            AD
> y         Year                    Year            1996; 96
> Y         Week year               Year            2009; 09
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which field to increase in your case.

The Calendar object has the following method:

```
public abstract void add(int field, int amount)
```

To add 1 day to your Calendar you can do this:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```